# CSS binding in KnockoutJS simply doesn't work

Tags: knockout.js

I'm using version 2.2.0 of KO, and I'm tryign to set the CSS for an `option` element like so:

```
<select data-bind="foreach: $data.answers, value: selectedAnswer">
    <option data-bind="css: $data.getScoringLevel, value: $data, text: $data.text"></option>
</select>
```

Here is the getScoringLevel() function:

```
// Answer.
var Answer = function () {
    var self = this;

    self.id = '';
    self.text = '';
    self.sendAnswerToWebService = true;
    self.scoringLevel = ko.observable(0);

    self.getScoringLevel = ko.computed(function () {
        switch (self.scoringLevel()) {
            case 1:
                return 'red';
            case 2:
                return 'orange';
            case 3:
                return 'yellow';
            default:
                return '';
        }
    }, self);
};
```

I can see the function is executed, sicne a breakpoint I place inside of it is hit, but the rendered HTML looks like this:

```
<option data-bind="css: $data.getScoringLevel, value: $data, text: $data.text" value="">Choose....</option>
```

There is no `class` attribute set for some reason. I was expecting, for exmample, `class="red"' somewhere.

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works. You see such html because default value of `scoringLevel` is 0 and your computed returns empty string. If you change it, for example to 1, red class will be assigned to the option.

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vyshniakov/DtDk7/1/

Comment: Pants :( OK, let me double check this. ScoringLevel is being set a value, I can verify that. Hmm, OK, let me double check.

Comment: It was a data issue after all, doh. Cheers anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Another example to look at: http://jsfiddle.net/TqgHb/3/ (revision 3 fixes JSLint warnings + uses `this` instead of closure to `self`)

The only changes I made were using `$index` for option value and removing unneeded `$data` in bindings + slight simplifications in Answer class.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. As I've just found out, the problem was a data issue and the colouring is working as expected. Cheers anyway.